# Can't access finding a File in the Android-Assets folder (Filesystem)

Tags: android, android-assets

I got a simple?! Problem that I can't solve...

I'm trying to access a File in the assets folder like this:

```
File file = new File("file:///android_asset/test/sample.pdf");
```

But the file is not available because this

```
System.out.println("#### "+file.exists());
```

returns false.

Now things are getting strange.. if im using the AssetsManager and debug that folder with

```
for(String asset : getAssets().list("test")) {
    System.out.println("### FOUND ASSET " +asset);
}
```

I'm getting a positive result. (The sample.pdf is displayed).

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I have no clue at all.

Comment: click this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#list(java.lang.String)... may be you have to check entire path `like test/sample.pdf` may be it will give desired result

Comment: Assets are not literal files at runtime - you can use them in many file-like ways and for example get a FileInputStream from one, but you may well (?) not be able to create an actual File object wrapping one.  Update: in fact you cannot, see the duplicate linked in the banner at the top of this page.

Comment: But if you can be content with a FileInputStream or even a FileDescriptor you do not need to make an actual file system copy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
File file = new File("android_asset/test/sample.pdf");